# Output a symbol from a bootstrap icon hex value

Tags: javascript, canvas, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I've learned how to retrieve bootstrap icon value.

Example (with glyphicon-trash icon):

html:

```
<div id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></div>
```

js:

```
var iconSymbol = window.getComputedStyle($('#icon')[0], ':before').content;
var result = iconSymbol.charCodeAt(1).toString(16);
console.log(result);
```

After that `result` is `e020`.

But after that I need to draw this symbol to the `canvas`.

Assuming that `value` is `e020`, I use the following code:

```
var label = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(value, 16));
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "52px Helvetica"
ctx.textAlign = "center"
ctx.fillStyle = "white"
ctx.fillText(label, pt.x, pt.y+4)
```

But after that I have only a rectangle symbol.

What do I need to implement to output the original symbol properly? May be there is a problem in font configuration or I have to try some encoding params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the same font as the bootstrap symbol does as a typical font does not have these symbols defined. Helvetica does not have these and it will likely in most cases revert back to the default sans-serif font in any case as most users don't have Helvetica installed.

Look at the font:

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.*
```

found in the [fonts/ folder](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/fonts). Set this font to canvas, then draw the symbol. You may have to preload the font via DOM.